# What does "(optional &optional prompt)" mean in a defun argument list?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I declare/define a function with

```
(defun defunname (optional &optional prompt)
  "Doc string"
  ...body...)
```

whats means (and how are parsed) argument `(optional &optional prompt)`?

Comment: See [12.2.3 Other Features of Argument Lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html) which was found by a trivial search. The first `optional` should probably be renamed to something more sensible, as it's required, and perhaps confusing in context.

Comment: Sorry. Look at line 83 on the page http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/url.el : there is this argument list. For this reason I've written `(optional &optional prompt)`

Comment: Ahh, I see. That defun just keeps the same parameter name as the function it wraps, `TeX-argument-prompt`, where it represents a boolean argument: "If OPTIONAL is not nil then the prompt will start with '(Optional)'." Anyway, after following the link posted in my first comment, is there a particular/focused question? I'm not sure how to read "how are parsed", eg.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be too hard for me :-(. With "How to parsed" I mean "How the function read it". After reading your link it is more clear. ps: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

The function "defunname" takes 1 argument (confusingly called "optional"), or 2 arguments (called "optional" and "prompt").

Comment: cornelius: The `&optional` keyword separates the list of mandatory arguments from the list of optional arguments. So argument `optional` is mandatory, but argument `prompt` is optional.